# Data transfer rate(Time taken to send or receive data) from ios to watchOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I've used watch connectivity framework to send data from iphone to apple watch and vice-versa. Is there a way to calculate the data transfer time?

Code:
    //
    //  ViewController.swift
    //  WatchCommunication_counter 
    //
    //  Created by Kaushik Shanmugam on 03/06/16.
    //  Copyright © 2016 Kaushik Shanmugam. All rights reserved.
    //

```
import UIKit
import WatchConnectivity
class ViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate{

//Communication session

let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
var phoneCounter = 0

@IBOutlet weak var labelcounter: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initWCSession()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



 func initWCSession(){
    session.delegate = self
    session.activateSession()
}

  func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String :           AnyObject]) {


    let msg = message["CounterValueFromWatch"]as! Int
      labelcounter.text = "Counter: \(msg)"
   }


  @IBAction func sendData(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Send data to apple watch

    let msg = ["CounterValueFromiphone" : phoneCounter++]
  session.sendMessage(msg, replyHandler: {(replay) -> Void in
}) {(error) -> Void in
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Calculate from what? Do you want to predict it or do you want to measure it? Do you want to know the latency or the data rate for a small amount of data? Btw, Apple recommends to do the session setup in the AppDelegate and not in a ViewController.

Comment: I'd want to measure the transfer rate ( in millisecs) from IOS to WatchOS and vice versa and the time to be displayed in a UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure a roundtrip:

```
let msg = ["CounterValueFromiphone" : phoneCounter++]
let start = NSDate()
session.sendMessage(msg, replyHandler: {(replay) -> Void in
   let end = NSDate()
   let timeInterval: Double = end.timeIntervalSinceDate(start)
   // display timeInterval in main queue
}) {(error) -> Void in
   let end = NSDate()
   let timeInterval: Double = end.timeIntervalSinceDate(start)
   // display timeInterval in main queue
}
```

I would not trust that you can compare a NSDate() measured on the iPhone and a NSDate() on the watch and rely on the difference.

Comment: Thanks.  Like you said it's just to compare the delay in transfer rate. Hence, I'd rely on the difference.

Comment: Is there also a way to find the latency?

Comment: If you send one or two bytes, I would say everything you measure ist pure latency.

Comment: But then I'm getting a delay of 0.8 seconds when I increment counter value from watch to iPhone and 0.6 seconds vice-versa. Is it normal? I'm also not using simulators now. Testing on device.

Comment: I never needed to be so fast. Nothing that surprises me. Apple probably also encrypts. Which should add heavily to latency.